# Read Lines From IIS Log

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

The purpose of this class is to read an IIS log (or multiple ones). One thing to note is that the columns can differ based on settings in IIS.

A couple of concerns that I have:

1. Is The ILogReader Interface neccessary?
2. Is the IFileReader the right way to allow me to stub out the `File.ReadAllLines` method?
3. Any other refactoring / clean code suggestions
4. How are my tests?
5. Is the static variable a nice and clean way to setup test data?

```
public class LogReader : ILogReader
{
    private IFileReader _fileReader;
    private List<string[]> _lines = new List<string[]>();
    private string[] _infoLines = new[] { "#Version:", "#Date:", "#Software:", "#Fields:" };

    public LogReader(IFileReader fileReader)
    {
        _fileReader = fileReader;
    }

    public List<LogEntry> LogEntries
    {
        get { 
            return _lines
                .Where(line => IsLogEntry(line))
                .Select(logEntryLine => new LogEntry(logEntryLine, Header))
                .ToList();
            }
    }

    private bool IsLogEntry(string[] line)
    {
        return !_infoLines.Contains(line.First());
    }

    public void AddFileToEntries(string fileName)
    {
        var newLines = _fileReader.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                        .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                        .ToList();

        _lines.AddRange(newLines);
    }

    public List<string> Header 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _lines
                .FirstOrDefault(l => l.First()
                .Contains("#Fields"))
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(field => field.Replace("-",""))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class LogReaderTests
{
    private ILogReader _logReader;
    Moq.Mock<IFileReader> _fileReaderMock;
    const string _logFileWith404String = "LogFileWith404";
    const string _logFileWith200String = "LogFileWith200";

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        _fileReaderMock = new Moq.Mock<IFileReader>();
        _fileReaderMock.Setup(fileReader => fileReader.ReadAllLines(_logFileWith404String)).Returns(TestData.LogFileWith404);
        _fileReaderMock.Setup(fileReader => fileReader.ReadAllLines(_logFileWith200String)).Returns(TestData.LogFileWith200);
        _logReader = new LogReader(_fileReaderMock.Object);
        _logReader.AddFileToEntries(_logFileWith404String);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OpenLogAndReadLines()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(_logReader.LogEntries.Count > 0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OpenLogAndReadHeaderEnsureThatFirstNonHeaderValueIsDate()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(_logReader.Header.First(),"date");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFirstValueCanConvertToDate()
    {
        var logEntries = _logReader.LogEntries;
        dynamic value = logEntries.First();
        var convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value.date);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void PrintAllLines()
    {
        var headerLine = String.Join("," , _logReader.Header);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(headerLine);
        foreach (var item in _logReader.LogEntries)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(",", item));
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllLinesWithNotFoundErrors()
    {
        var notFoundLines = from logEntries in _logReader.LogEntries
                                where ((dynamic)logEntries).scstatus == "404"
                                select logEntries;
        foreach (dynamic item in notFoundLines)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("404", item.scstatus);
        }

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReadMultipleFilesIntoLogParser()
    {
        int realLineCount = TestData.LogFileWith404
            .Count(entry => FileDoesNotContainHeaderLine(entry));

        realLineCount += TestData.LogFileWith200
            .Count(entry => FileDoesNotContainHeaderLine(entry));

        _logReader.AddFileToEntries(_logFileWith200String);

        Assert.IsTrue(_logReader.LogEntries.Count() == realLineCount);
    }

    private bool FileDoesNotContainHeaderLine(string c)
    {
        return !new[] { "#Version:", "#Date:", "#Software:", "#Fields:" }
                    .Contains(c.Split(' ')[0]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look.

> Is The ILogReader Interface neccessary?

It is not, as long as you reasonably expect that it will stay with just this one log reader. I think it is not out of the question that you might adapt your application to also account for different types of logs so I would leave it in there for future purposes.

It also indicates more that you are talking about *a* logreader instead of *the* logreader, which you'll need when adding more logs.

> Is the IFileReader the right way to allow me to stub out the File.ReadAllLines method?

Yes, definitely. External dependencies should be stubbed out into their own layer so you have no interference with the actual system and thus stick to unit tests and not integration tests (they should live together, not replace eachother).

As a sidenote here: are you using an actual sample logfile or are you hardcoding the strings? I feel like you could benefit from adding an additional layer for mocking data in your unit tests. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409912/unit-testing-valid-inputs-to-a-method/22410273#22410273) on that subject.

> Any other refactoring / clean code suggestions

Honestly.. No. Your code is very clean and slim and it looks like you have little room for improvement, you're fine on that aspect.

> How are my tests?

I prefer explicit `private` mentioning for variables. It leaves no room for confusion and it keeps your types aligned with eachother.

```
private ILogReader _logReader;
private Moq.Mock _fileReaderMock;
private const string _logFileWith404String = "LogFileWith404";
private const string _logFileWith200String = "LogFileWith200";
```

When it comes to unit testing method naming I very much appreciate the approach as described in [The art of Unit Testing, 2nd Edition by Roy Osherove](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617290890) which comes down to

```
[UnitOfWorkName]_[ScenarioUnderTest]_[ExpectedBehaviour]
```

For example for your method named *OpenLogAndReadHeaderEnsureThatFirstNonHeaderValueIsDate* this could become

```
ReadingLogHeader_FirstNonHeaderValue_IsDate
```

Now you have clearly separated your method name's intentions and it's more easily to see where the problem is located when tests fail.

There are two methods (`TestFirstValueCanConvertToDate` and `PrintAllLines`) that don't test anything thus they shouldn't be marked with the `TestMethodAttribute`. Likewise they should be `private` if they're just helper methods (although I don't see the purpose of `TestFirstValueCanConvertToDate`).

> Is the static variable a nice and clean way to setup test data?

I assume you are referring to the `const` variables considering I don't see any `static` behaviour aside from that.

No, I don't think they're necessary. It won't have any impact on your performance and you shouldn't have another class that tests the same class so it shouldn't be used for that purpose either.

That being said: it doesn't negatively impact you either so it is yours to choose if you keep them or not.

Comment: Thanks, helps allot. In terms of the static variable part, the TestData.LogFileWith200 actually is just a string[] inside a class taken from a log file (to be clean). This is so that I don't go and read the file (as you mentioned to avoid integration testing). My idea was that this is mocked out? Thanks for the very thoughtful review!

Comment: O yes, the constants are there to make it a bit more reusable as well as to promote reuse although I can see how this might be a bit of an overkill

Comment: The reuse isn't relevant here since you will never create multiple instances of your test class so it doesn't do anything. But yes, you basically incorporated a datasource layer for your tests which is what I would do as well.

Comment: I actually did read the art of unit testing, very good book. I find it a bit laborious to write my methods like that and am experimenting with different options. I do actually reuse one of the strings in ReadMultipleFilesIntoLogParser (yes, I know most people say you should only consider reuse after using it 3 times) and so to keep a standard I renamed both. Thinking about it now though I see your point that it's been refactored out to soon. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

> Is the IFileReader the right way to allow me to stub out the File.ReadAllLines method?

I'm not sure. In which component is `IFileReader` defined?

An alternative would be to use a delegate: `Func<string, string[]>`.

I'm unsure of this answer because I don't know/understand Moq, but IMO using a delegate instead of an interface would let you pass `File.ReadAllLines` directly as the delegate parameter ...

```
LogReader reader = new LogReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines);
```

... instead of defining and instantiating a class which implements the `IFileReader` interface and uses `File.ReadAllLines` in its implementation ...

```
interface IFileReader
{
    string[] ReadAllLines(string filename);
}

class FileReader : IFileReader
{
    public string[] ReadAllLines(string filename)
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    }
}

LogReader reader = new LogReader(new FileReader());
```